# Avoid fluttering on mouse hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a left nav menu for my web page, which is to look something like the following image:

Here is the jsfiddle of the problem I am facing. http://jsfiddle.net/rzr4Z/

My html looks like the following

```html
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#first-page" id="first_id">First</a><img src="images/navbar-icons/first.png" />
    </li>
    <li><a href="#second-page" id="second_id">Second</a><img src="images/navbar-icons/second.png" />
    </li>
    <li><a href="#third-page" id="third_id">Third</a><img src="images/navbar-icons/third.png" /> <img
        src="images/navbar-icons/third.png" />
        <ul id="side-menu">
            <li><img src="images/navbar-icons/submenu-img.png" alt="sub menu image" />
            </li>
            <li>Sub-menu item 1</li>
            <li>Sub-menu item 2</li>
            <li>Sub-menu item 1</li>
        </ul></li>
    <li><a href="fourth-page" id="fourth_id">Fourth</a><img src="images/navbar-icons/fourth.png" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```css
ul#nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

ul#nav li {
    font-size: 250%;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 7px 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul#nav li a {
    display: block;
}

ul#nav li a:link,ul#nav li a:visited {
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul#nav li a:hover,ul#nav li a:active {
    color: #a61607;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul#nav li img {
    display: none;
}

ul#nav a:hover#first_id+img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
}

ul#nav a:hover#second_id+img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
}

ul#nav a:hover#third_id+img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
}

ul#nav a:hover#fourth_id+img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
}

ul#nav li ul#side-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

ul#nav li:hover ul#side-menu {
    font-size: 30%;
    list-style-type: none;
    line-height: 2px;
    color: #a61607;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 310px;
    left: 250px;
}

ul#nav li:hover ul#side-menu li {
    float: none;
}

ul#nav li:hover ul#side-menu li img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Instead of doing something like,

```css
ul#nav a:hover+img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
}
```

I had to use different ID's for each of the li elements in the css because each of the rollover image has a different size and width so that I could adjust them individually for their correponding rollover positions. Is using different ID's for each of the menu items the right way to get the desired effect?

The main problem however is when I hover the images for each of the menu items, I start getting a fluttering effect, and the hover effect doesn't look easy to the eyes with that kind of fluttering.
The images for the sub-menu (the sub-menu items do appear, but the img doesn't appear) also doesn't appear when hovering over `#third-page` menu item.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this fluttering, and getting the correct effects for this menu?

Comment: A jsfiddle would be appreciated.

Comment: @Jerska: Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rzr4Z/

Comment: Would you be open to using a javascript solution? and if so, jQuery?

Comment: the images are too big to show it in that place, consider using smaller images or displaying it on other place

Comment: You have to understand why this is happening, and then maybe you'll reconsider your question.  When you hover over "Third," the image is shown on the page which pushes the list item over, which cause the hover, mouse out event to fire since the mouse is no longer on the list item.  At this point, the image is hidden since the mouse isn't firing the hover event.  But then when the image is hidden and the list item is now over the mouse again, the image is shown.  Essentially, you're firing the same two events over and over again ( Mouse on/mouse not on) which makes it appear to "flutter."

Comment: @Stieffers: Yes, I did realize that. These images that I am using in the above fiddle are an example. In my case, the images appear over the li elements (eg: `position: relative; top: -25px;` for hover event  to show the image} and the flutter effect still occurs. How do you recommned resolving the issue then in this case? ;-/

Comment: If the images are appearing over the list element, than you're blocking the list element and it won't think the mouse is hovering over it, so it's essentially the same thing.  You could possibly add the hover event to the image, so that if you're mouse is on the image, you continue to show it.  Edit:  Here's a JS fiddle that sort of helps. Should give you a general idea. http://jsfiddle.net/PF35v/

Comment: @Stieffers: Tried this `img` hover. Though it does solve this problem to some extent (noy fully solved) in my jsfiddle example, but in my real website, is is not giving the required effect and the fluttering still happens :( I really had thought getting rollover effects would have been simple and the images appearing over the over another element, but doesn't look quite so

Comment: @Rodik: Yes, I can that as well. Do you mind putting a jsfiddle with the above example and how JavaScript can solve this?

Comment: @Stieffers: Thanks for your help. I did try your jsfiddle and looks like the third item still has the fluttering  ;-/ Ideally, even a little fluttering won't be a good thing since this is the main navigation bar. I am not sure how to get this kind of rollover effect with the images appearing over the previous element and then disappearing after hover complete

Answer (score 2):

Using different IDs is fine in your case. As for the fluttering problem, I was able to eliminate it by changing this part of your CSS:

```
ul#nav a:hover#first_id+img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
}

ul#nav a:hover#second_id+img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
}

ul#nav a:hover#third_id+img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
}

ul#nav a:hover#fourth_id+img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
}
```

to this:

```
ul#nav li:hover #first_id+img {
    display: block;
}

ul#nav li:hover #second_id+img {
    display: block;
}

ul#nav li:hover #third_id+img {
    display: block;
}

ul#nav li:hover #fourth_id+img {
    display: block;
}
```

What was happening was, when you hover over the third link, the size of the image would push the link so that it was centered within the li. And if your mouse happened to be hovering to the left or right of the link once the image appeared, you weren't hovering over the link anymore, so it would disappear, then immediately reappear because now you are again hovering over the link... etc.

Detecting the :hover over the li itself fixes this so that the image appears if you are hovering over the li itself, regardless of if you are hovering over the link, image, or any space around them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't detect the `:hover` over li since the width of each `li` element is too wide to look decent for a rollover effect. Secondly, I had the `position:relative;top:-25px` for a reason since I wanted the image to overlap (rollover) the corresponding `li a` element hover. In this, when you have replaced the it with `display:block`, it actually is not a rollover effect. ;-/

Comment: I just took what was in your jsfiddle.. anyway best of luck

Answer (score 2):

The trick to fixing your issue is two things:

1) Make the `LI` items fixed-width
2) Make the "hover" effect occur on the `LI`, not on the `A`

The reason you are experiencing "flicker" is exactly what's been described above. When you are applying the `:hover` effect to the `A` tag, and the tags aren't fixed in size, you wind up in some positions where your mouse causes the `:hover`, the `:hover` moves the object that caused it out from under the mouse - and that causes the effect to end, putting the object back under the mouse - which causes it again. Endless cause'n'effect which gives you flicker.

By putting the `:hover` effect on the `LI` instead, you cause the `:hover` to be raised whether the mouse is over the `A` OR the `IMG` - so when the `IMG` tag pops visible and everything shifts size, your mouse is still hovering over the `LI` that contains both elements - and voila - no flicker.

There **is** another issue caused by your approach, however, due to the size of the images. Because your images are shunting things downward due to their height (big images) - when you get to the bottom of the image, and roll over the next `LI` - everything will shift out from under your mouse and cause a similar issue. This, however, will generally not cause flicker per-se.

Please see the following [update to your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzr4Z/4/).

As you will see, the "height" issue occurs on the "Third" entry. This, too, is solvable by explicitly setting height / width and using images of an exact size - OR (more effectively) by using `background: url(...);` CSS rules rather than `IMG` tags - because they are far easier to clip / resize.

If you need an example of some other CSS-based rollover menus with sub-menus, please take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/25J4e/), which demonstrates a more modular approach to dropdown menus and such. It could be modified to suit your needs pretty easily with the use of background graphics.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I gave the bounty since the answer much sense to me. However, as I wrote earlier in one of my comments, I can't detect the `:hover` over `li` since the width of each li element is too wide to look decent for a rollover effect. I will try to change the approach as I see in above fiddles or incorporate something else. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens when we do not specify following css attributes:

1. min-width, max-width, and
2. min-height, max-height

And carefully using the following css attributes can help:

```
#parent_id:hover
{
  //use borders to find space required for correct width/height
}

#parent_id>#child_id:hover
{
  //use borders to find space required for correct width/height
}

#parent_id:hover, #child_id:hover
{
  //use borders to find space required for correct width/height
}
```

So make sure that you add these.

**Remember this always:**

Never do css without borders, always make sure that you add borders to almost all nodes,
this helps to clearly understand how much space is being occupied and it is more easy to workout errors in css like this

```
ul#nav {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
position:absolute;
height:300px;
width:200px;
max-height:300px;
max-width:200px;
border:5px solid red;
overflow:hidden;
}

ul#nav li {
border:1px solid green;
font-size: 250%;
line-height: 25px;
max-height:200px;
padding: 7px 0;
margin-top: 10px;
max-height:50px;
}
ul#nav li a {
border:1px solid black;
}
ul#nav li a:link,ul#nav li a:visited {
color: #333333;
text-decoration: none;
}

ul#nav li a:hover,ul#nav li a:active {
max-height:50px;
color: #a61607;
text-decoration: none;
}

ul#nav li img {
display: none;
}

ul#nav a:hover#first_id+img {
display: block;
}

ul#nav a:hover#second_id+img {
display: block;
}

ul#nav a:hover#third_id+img {
display: block;
}

ul#nav a:hover#fourth_id+img {
display: block;
}

ul#nav li ul#side-menu {
display: none;
}

ul#nav li:hover ul#side-menu {
font-size: 30%;
list-style-type: none;
line-height: 2px;
color: #a61607;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 310px;
left: 250px;
}

ul#nav li:hover ul#side-menu li {
float: none;
}

ul#nav li:hover ul#side-menu li img {
position: absolute;
width:48px;
height:48px;
top: 400px;
left: 0px;
}​
```

**Now it is not fluttering**

Comment: **Why did you not mark it as the answer, it is not fluttering, I did what you asked for!!**

Comment: Moderators should step in to handle such a waste of time and effort, given that what was asked for has been aptly done.

Comment: I don't think this is working. I updated the fiddle and the fluttering still occurs as it was occuring on the third item earlier as well. Here's the new forked fiddlee with your changes: http://jsfiddle.net/6ETbR/

Comment: always be careful reading others' code, do not miss any part of code. I have posted another answer, try that if it does not work I will find a better one.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
ul#nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    max-height:300px;
    max-width:200px;
    border:5px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

My code:

```
ul#nav {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
position:absolute;
height:300px;
width:200px;
max-height:300px;
max-width:200px;
border:5px solid red;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

**Carefully look at my last answer, you have missed significant attributes like        height:300px; and width:200px;**

---

**Simply specifying max,min-prefixed attributes is not enough, you should add specific height and width settings, only then fluttering disappears.**

Comment: I have given the correct answer yet neither do you vote up nor comment, strange behaviour. Do you know the meaning of **fluttering**.

**Image increasing size on hover is not fluttering.** Fluttering is something else. I hope you know it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do:

```
ul#nav li a{display: block;}
```

or

```
ul#nav li{text-align: left;}
```

so `mouseleave` doesn't fire on `mouseenter`